# jsonp to create seo friendly code

Tags: json

Is there a way to get the JSON code to convert to text so Search engines can read the rendered code as normal text rather than json tags

sample Source Code

```
 <div data-binding-id="repeat1" data-binding-repeat="{{manufactures.data}}" class="span2">
{{jsondata}}
</div>
```

I would like it to do the following:

```
 <div data-binding-id="repeat1" data-binding-repeat="{{manufactures.data}}" class="span2">
I am now text so the search engines can read it correctly
</div>
```

Is this possible??

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You just need something in back end that will set `jsondata` and something in front end that will render the page. [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net) for example.

You must say which language you are using.